# Gmaps4rails marker depending on current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-markers, cancan, gmaps4rails

Is there a way to view markers using gmaps4rails gem, depending on the current user login? I'm not sure if there was any chance it might have worked out, but I tried using the cancan gem in combination but it only results in all of the markers disappearing. Unfortunately I have no other idea how to carry on. So what I am trying to achieve is to make markers visible depending on which user is currently logged in. I am grateful for any help!

Current code of relations_controller:

```
    def index

    @relations = Relation.all

@hash1 = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@relations) do |relation, marker|
    # something like "if current_user == relation.user_id" ?
    marker.lat relation.childlat
    marker.lng relation.childlng

    marker.picture({
              :url    => ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path("childgross.png"),
              :width  => "45",
              :height => "45"
             })
 end

@hash2 = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@relations) do |relation, marker|
    marker.lat relation.kigalat
    marker.lng relation.kigalng
    marker.picture({
            :url    => ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path("persongross.png"),
            :width  => "45",
            :height => "45"
            })
 end
end
```

code in relations index view:

```
    <%=raw @hash1.to_json %>
    <%=raw @hash2.to_json %>

<script>
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({provider: {},internal: {id: 'map'}},function(){
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash1.to_json %>);
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash2.to_json %>);
handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You want to change the markers depending on the user? Or to show or not to show markers? Both options are possible. Why don't you show the code where you create your markers?

Comment: @Pablo that is a good question. I edited my question and added the code. Don't be confused I have two hashes, one where I create markers for children and one for the markers of kindergardens (I am not sure if its done this way). I want the children to be shown depending on the user. So if the child does not belong to the current user the marker shouldn't be shown in the map. I removed my cancan approach because it didn't work..

Comment: It seems to me you can create the first hash only with relations belonging to current_user. And the second hash with all relations. Use ‘@user_rel = current_user.relations’ or ‘@user_rel = Relation.where(user_id: current_user.id)’ depending on your models.

Comment: thanks alot! it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnaks to @Pablo It just came to me... I just had to replace `@relations = Relation.all` with `@relations = Relation.where(user_id: current_user.id)`